# Mac App: Protect downloaded video files for offline viewing.

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am building a Mac app that can stream videos, but I would also like to provide offline viewing support. I would let the user download the videos, however, I do not want the video files to be accessible to user.

Is there a way to ensure that the user cannot access the video files? I would like it to behave similarly to how iOS files are stored in sandbox environment and not accessible to users. I have considered encryption/decryption, but am concerned the amount of time to decrypt would be too high due to large size of some of the video files (some over an hour long), leading to bad user experience.

Comment: How could encrypting files prevent the user from accessing them?  Why aren't iOS users able to access files in the sandbox environment?  I am afraid what you are saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think they are referring to needing the ability to download videos to the app so they can be watched offline, but not made available on the file system so the videos can be stolen and/or distributed. @ElTomato

Comment: If you don't want the user to casually play back downloaded videos, what you can do is to save a clip as Data (NSData).  But that doesn't not complete blockly them from opening files.  One could just write their own non-sandboxed application to access files anywhere.  You misunderstand the objective of sandboxing an application.